# Cambiar navbar al hacer scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, navbar

Estoy trabajando sobre un sitio tratando de hacer esto con el navbar, pero con bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_parallax.htm
La idea es un navbar trasparente, al hacer scroll cambie con una animación. Al volver al punto inicial la navbar vuelve a ser trasparente. Yo hice una función con jquery, cambiando las clases al hacer scroll con toogleClass pero no resulta. Cómo se hace?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    
    function myFunction() {
        var navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
            navbar.toggleClass("navbar" + "navbar-expand-lg" + "fixed-top" + "nav-white" + "sombreado" + "animate-top");
        } else {
            navbar.toggleClass("navbar" + "navbar-expand-lg" + "fixed-top" + "nav");
        }      
    }
```

```css
.first > div {
    color: #fff;
}

section {
    height: 350px;   
}

.first {
    padding-top: 70px;
    /*Imagen*/
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');
    height: auto;
    /*Para crear efecto parallax*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.nav {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.nav-white {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.nav-white .navbar-brand {
    color: black;
}

.nav-white .navbar-nav li a {
    color: black;
}

.nav-white .fa.fa-navicon {
    color: black;
}

.sombreado {
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
}

.animate-top{
    animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Transparent Navbar</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
         
        </head>
        
        <body>
            
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top nav" id="myNavbar">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu de Navegacion">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 1</a>
                        </li>     
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <section class="first row">
                <div class="col">                
                    <h2>MAIN</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                
                </div>      
            </section>    
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 2</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>    
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 3</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas mezclando vanilla javascript con jQuery.  La variable `navbar` no es un objeto jQuery, por lo que la funcion `toggleClass` no te va a funcionar.  Necesitas encerrar la variable en el operador de jQuery `$()`.  Algo asi:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    
    function myFunction() {
        var navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
            $(navbar).toggleClass("navbar" + "navbar-expand-lg" + "fixed-top" + "nav-white" + "sombreado" + "animate-top");
        } else {
            $(navbar).toggleClass("navbar" + "navbar-expand-lg" + "fixed-top" + "nav");
        }      
    }
```

```css
.first > div {
    color: #fff;
}

section {
    height: 350px;   
}

.first {
    padding-top: 70px;
    /*Imagen*/
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080/?random');
    height: auto;
    /*Para crear efecto parallax*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.nav {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.nav-white {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.nav-white .navbar-brand {
    color: black;
}

.nav-white .navbar-nav li a {
    color: black;
}

.nav-white .fa.fa-navicon {
    color: black;
}

.sombreado {
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
}

.animate-top{
    animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Transparent Navbar</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
         
        </head>
        
        <body>
            
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top nav" id="myNavbar">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu de Navegacion">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 1</a>
                        </li>     
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">TITLE 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <section class="first row">
                <div class="col">                
                    <h2>MAIN</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>                
                </div>      
            </section>    
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 1</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 2</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>    
            
            <section class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>TITLE 3</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-zDnhMsjVZfS3hiP7oCBRmfjkQC4fzxVxFhBx8Hkz2aZX8gEvA/jsP3eXRCvzTofP" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            
       </body>
</html>
```